# wicked_pdf PDF generation: Reset page numbers and start numbering from 1 again

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm using this code in pdf footer to get page numbers at the footer.

```
<script>
  function number_pages() {
    var vars={};
    var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    for(var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = decodeURIComponent(z[1]);}
    var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
    for(var i in x) {
      var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
      for(var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
    }
  }
</script>
```

this works perfectly as it supposes to, what I'm not able to achieve is resetting the page number when the code reaches to a custom tag [reset_page_number], the code should reset the page numbers and start from 1 again.

Any idea to achieve that?

Comment: Without knowing ahead of time what page a reset should occur on, I can only suggest splitting it up so that each section renders as a separate PDF, then combining them into a final resulting PDF. The JS you posted only searches for elements within the content of the header/footer HTML with the context of the URL which `wkhtmltopdf` keeps track of which page it's inserting the header into.

Comment: let's say that I know when the page should reset counting, how can I do that?

Comment: Here's a quick example of how you might do that: https://gist.github.com/unixmonkey/e0fa1decd628301482b4480966e3dafa

Comment: Did you see the above comment? Is it helpful to you at all?